# Wacom tablet multi-monitor mapping issues

Tags: drivers, gnome, wacom, graphics-tablet

In GNOME Settings, I enabled "Map to single monitor". I also tried `xsetwacom set 14 MapToOutput 1920x1080+1920+0` (the middle one of 3 1920x1080 monitors), but this also doesn't work. I can use the full height of the tablet, but the first third of the tablet stays mapped to all 3 monitors. Placing the pen on the right two thirds of the tablet causes the pointer to clip to the right screen edge of the right monitor.

Not sure if that's got something to do with this, but sometimes, I get different outputs for `xsetwacom --list devices` after disconnecting and reconnecting the USB cable:

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices   
Wacom Intuos S Pad pad                  id: 14  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus               id: 15  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S Pen eraser               id: 17  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos S Pen cursor               id: 18  type: CURSOR
```

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus          id: 14  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S eraser          id: 15  type: ERASER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are affected by the "Android misdetect" issue that plagues users of the CTL-6100, CTL-6100WL, CTL-4100, and CTL-4100WL. The firmware on these tablets effectively disables the right half of the device when it believe it is connected to an Android device (in order to have the tablet map properly to a typically-portrait Android screen). The firmware is known to mis-detect Ubuntu and other Linux distributions as Android, which causes symptoms similar to what you report.

To force the tablet back into "PC mode", you can hold the two outermost ExpressKeys for until the status light turns off and then on again. This takes around 3-4 seconds. Once in "PC mode" the entire tablet surface should be usable and mapped to whatever area you've set in GNOME (the entire desktop or a specific monitor). Unfortunately you'll need to perform this workaround any time you reboot or re-connect the tablet since the firmware will re-detect the system as Android when it is initializing.

For more details, see https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Known-Issues#android-misdetect

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'm using Manjaro now but never had these issues with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This xetwacom works well for my with Intuos BT S: xsetwacom set 19 MapToOutput 1920x1080+1920+0, where 19 is the ID of my stylus.

Instead of the ID of the pad (14), did you try to use the ID of the stylus (15) for the xsetwacom command?